# Magento SUPEE 8788 admin side blank in 1.9.2.4

Tags: checkout, patches, admin-panel, supee-8788, magento1.9.2.4

I have installed the SUPEE 8788 patch without using SSH. I am using following link

[How to install SUPEE-8788 without SSH](https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh)

Now the admin panel is blank after login. And can't place orders in frontend

Comment: check your apache log for the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to clear cache from backend by going to file manager to /var/cache folder. Then refresh browser. Had exactly same issue.

If this doesnt work. Revert the patch, and make sure complier is DISABLED!. Then install the patch one more time.

Comment: Removed the cache folder. But it is not working. Compiler is disabled

Answer (score 0):

Please turn on error reporting and enable developer mode. Then again check admin panel. If you see error message there, then you can further debug for this issue and fix it.